# Creating a Token on Remix - Ethereum Script issue need Help :/

Tags: remix

Hey fam i was coding a Token but i dont know what im doing wrong Remix-Ethereum showing me this Error :

```sh
Lalafinu.sol:32:1: ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'ILLEGAL'
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
^
```

This is the part

```js
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
```

Comment: 32:1: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

Answer (score 0):

Interface opens and closes with a curly brace:

```
interface IERC20{
    ...
}
```

Since you are missing that, the compiler shows an error.

Comment: Now i did it like this : 
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20{

}
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**

and this problem pops of : 
ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum definition.
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
^